# How to delete specific csv filename end with random number?

Tags: batch-file

I have csv files as below.

```
customer_1604912280077.csv
customer_1604977680453.csv
customer_1604998080667.csv
..and so on
```

may i know how to use batch command to delete all these files customer_random number.csv ?

del command not able to use due to filename end all is random numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

del customer_*.csv

should delete all files named "customer_<kbd>anything</kbd>.csv"